# How to replace one mxml instance with another?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml

I am pretty new to Flex.

What I am trying to achieve is to have two different layouts and initialize them based on the user's choice. Each of these layouts is defined in its own mxml component.

I have two components:

and

I could add both in the beginning and have only one visible but I don't want to go down that road. What I tried so far is to have an event handler that replaces the current instance but I hit a wall. Let's say that LeftAligned is the component initialized first and then I want to change it with RightAligned. Now:

- If I try to replace the lement based on its id: newElement:RightAligned = new RightAligned(); LayoutArea = newElement; I get a implicit coercion error that it can't convert RightAligned to LeftAligned.
- If I try to removeElement(LayoutArea); addElement(newElement); then I get an exception thrown from other parts of the application that call LayoutArea's methods (event based).

What solutions are there for this? Thank you

Comment: If I understood what your question correctly, look into the concept of [View States](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html) You can easily change between two (or more) states while keeping anything you want to share between the states/views.

Comment: @PeteTNT is it possible to create view state dinamically?

Comment: @PeteTNT what if I, let's say, have 1000 layouts?

Comment: You should look into and use view states as PeteTNT suggested. It's sounds perfect what for what you're doing in the question. It however, it is not something you would do with 1000 "layouts". There is a very nice syntax for controlling what is displayed and when using view states. But it will break down (in terms of performance and maintainability) if you introduce a boat load of view states. You don't add view states dynamically (typically), you specify them in MXML and programmatically switch between the states you define.

Comment: If you want something that is more dynamic, you would not use view states and would code up something that added/removed objects from a container. The errors you encountered are likely due to your design, if you show that code someone can probably suggest how to do it.

Comment: @SunilD. Do bindings that are set in an mxml component work if you add the element programatically?

Comment: Yes, but you have to initialize them. For example: an MXML component has a public property called `userName`. Inside the component there is a `Label` object that is bound to `userName`. When you dynamically add this MXML component, you would set the value of the component's `userName` property, and the `Label` would display the new value.